# import parse not working

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, parse-platform

I'm using android studio 1.1.0. I've added the parse library to my project successfully in gradle. see screenshots. But when I try to import com.parse.* or type Parse and then Alt(Option) + Enter, IDE gives error. It doesn't find the library. Here is screenshot:

[image: parse issue]

And here is the gradle file that doesn't have sync error. It synched successfully.

[image: Gradle]

Comment: ./gradlew clean assemble   on cli in proj root

Comment: fyi .. there is diff between ['*.jar']  and listing each of the ./libs... folders jars explicitly in the 'compile' section of dependencies.. try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After studying the problem for a few days, finally I've found the reason. If I use relative path in gradle, it doesn't work. If I use absolute path it works. Here is the absolute path:

```
compile files('/Users/farhadrubel/AndroidStudioProjects/android/MyProject/libs/Parse-1.8.2.jar')
```

You can add the library with it's absolute path easily. Remove it from your gradle file (if it's already added). Then right click on the jar file inside lib. Click on Add As Library from context menu.

[image: Add android library in gradle file easily]

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation

1.) Download latest Parse and unzip - Latest is 1.8.2
https://parse.com/downloads/android/Parse/latest

2.) Add the parse-*.jar to your app's libs folder and add the following to the gradle.build file in dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
}
```

That should work, works well for me, Android studio version - 1.1.0

In any case if it doesnt, try File-->Invalidate Caches and Restart

Comment: Did you try to get 1.5 Parse version? I was trying to get the latest version and  I was getting a kind of that error. Please, try to use that and let me know if it worked!